# YoutubeAPI v3 - Setting thumbnail returns Completed status, but no thumbnail is set on video

Tags: c#, .net-core, youtube-data-api

I am developing a .NET Core 2.2 WebAPI service for uploading videos to YouTube. Alongside uploading the video, service must upload a custom thumbnail to the uploaded video.

I could not find a code sample for this particular task, so I've implemented thumbnail upload based [on the sample for uploading a video](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/code_samples/dotnet#upload_a_video). I've tried the upload on numerous videos (belonging to the authorised account) and tried uploading various thumbnails with different sizes and shapes, but none of them made it to the video.

```
using (var youtubeService = await GetYouTubeService())
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(request.ThumbnailFilePath, FileMode.Open))
{
    var thumbnailSetRequest = youtubeService.Thumbnails.Set(request.YoutubeId, fileStream, "image/jpeg");
thumbnailSetRequest.ProgressChanged += ThumbnailSetRequest_ProgressChanged;
    var result = await thumbnailSetRequest.UploadAsync();
    if (result.Status == UploadStatus.Failed)
    {
        Logger.Error($"Unable to upload thumbnail for video (YT id: {request.YoutubeId})");
    }
}
```

Every time I've executed this code no exception was thrown and the returned `result.Status` was always set to Complete, but no thumbnail was set on the requested video. What have I missed? Why is the API giving me the information that the upload was successful when it obviously wasn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this really is the right code to upload a thumbnail, but for some reason sometimes it does not work. I've executed this code without any changes a few days after posting this question while I was testing another part of the application and saw that this time a thumbnail was added.

It would be very useful if I knew why this happened, but since this is the Google's recommended channel for help, and no answer was provided by them, it will remain a mistery.